# Rotate the screen manually to Landscape and there is a white bar left behind on left of screen where the old status bar was placed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have one screen in my app that I need in portrait as I use a video camera on this screen.

So I load my view then call this method:

```
- (void)rotate
{ 
CGAffineTransform landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(90));
landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate (landscapeTransform, +80.0, +80.0);

[self.tabBarController.view setTransform:landscapeTransform];
self.tabBarController.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |  
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
self.tabBarController.view.bounds  = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 480.0, 320.0);
self.tabBarController.view.center  = CGPointMake (240.0, 160.0);
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}
```

There is a 20 pixel wide white area along left hand side of the screen, where the status bar used to be drawn while the screen was in portrait mode.

Same problem exists when I replace the self.tabBarController.view in the above code with self.view 
Maybe there is someway to target the very root view of the app if self.view is not that view.

The xib for this view is 480 pixels in size. Can anybody give me some advise as how to fix this problem?

When I take this view out and make appear in a an app without any navbar and placed directly on the main view it transforms ok without the white space on the left.

Many Thanks,
-Code

Comment: did you try changing the orientation first and then setting bounds of tabBarController ??

Comment: your code works perfect for me

Answer (score 1):

You should trust rotation to ios default orientation changes.

In order to programmatically rotate to desired orientation:

```
//set statusbar to the desired rotation position
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft animated:NO];

//present/dismiss viewcontroller in order to activate rotating.
UIViewController *mVC = [[[UIViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
[self presentModalViewController:mVC animated:NO];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

Hopefully it will help!

P.S.Tested on sdk 3.2.5 ios 5.0.1.